# Doubts with Ripley's K function Interpretation

Tags: qgis, r, graphics

I'm a self-taught person, I'm studying the K Ripley's function and I would need some person who give me some advices.

First, I have written a little script of R in QGIS processor:

```
##Point pattern analysis=group
##Layer=vector
##Titulo=string
##showplots
library("maptools")
library("spatstat")    
K <- Kest(as.ppp(Layer))
plot(K, main=Titulo)
```

Then, to test the different results I have  prepared 3 layers about the same extension. One regular, other random, and the last clustered, with 100 points each one. This is the random graphic ploted:

[image]

This is my question:

The random graph should be equal than the poisson line, Why the observed K is higher than poisson one? (I see the lines shapes are equal) Is this due to the little number of points?

Here are the files to reproduce it (included script for QGIS).

[Zip file](https://mega.co.nz/#!RYBiBbSQ!sK5tQ7zr2lYDD5xXQLli0HVqWCYOQg3VYFjpfCQm8Tk)

Comment: Please note that the format of this Q&A page requires us to stick to one question per post. Feel free to open multiple threads if you have more than one question. Also pure R/stats questions might be more suited to the stats stackexchange community

Comment: I have removed some questions. I'm sorry. :)

Comment: I think you should ask for moving your question to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), change the title to reflect your post and add an [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). You can [flag it](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: Well, this question was migrated form Cross Validated. I've changed the title as you suggest and added a file to reproduce the graphic. And flag it? That's for problematic questions. Is my question problematic? :(

Comment: Sorry, I've mixed with other question. This has not migrated from Cross Validation. I'll post there as well.

Comment: Flag your question to  "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" _This question needs a moderator's attention. Please describe exactly what's wrong._ You can ask for moving your question. Do not ask two times the same question

Comment: This is probably the right place for the question. It's currently unanswerable because it does not contain enough information. How exactly was your "random" dataset constructed?

Comment: You can download the file. I added it a few hours ago. In that file there's the R script I've been used for the graphic also. So, I think you should reproduce it if you like.